# Magento 2 add block phtml to every page

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, modal-popup

I have a modal to show in every page, my modal was created in phtml file which using custom block file. i want to show this modal in every page of magento, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this by following layout xml file.

```
app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

the content would be like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        // reference a container to show your model
    </body>
</page>
```

**NOTE:** you can refer any core module's layout file for above content.